# Calling PostgreSQL procedure contains insert from Spring boot

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jdbc

I have a Spring boot (3.04) app, which wants to call a PostreSQL procedure. This procedure inserts into a table and there is one return value as String. When I try to call it, I got an error:
"Cannot execute INSERT in a read-only transaction"
I tried to annotate this method with @Transactional annotation and tried to get TransactionManager and starting transaction by hand, but these were not working.
I use jdbcTemplate.call to try executing liek this:

```
Map<String, Object> result = jdbcTemplate.call(new CallableStatementCreator() {

                @Override
                public CallableStatement createCallableStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
                    CallableStatement stmnt = con.prepareCall(sql);
                    stmnt.setString(1, p1);
                    stmnt.setString(2, p2);
                    stmnt.registerOutParameter(3, Types.VARCHAR);

                    return stmnt;
                }
            }, paramList);

            return (String) result.get(statusParam.toString());
```

Another try:

```
private String new_v(String p1, String p2, String sql) {
        String role= "";

        PlatformTransactionManager tm=new DataSourceTransactionManager(databaseConfiguration.getDatasource());
        TransactionTemplate tpl=new TransactionTemplate(tm);
        tpl.setReadOnly(false);
        tpl.execute(status -> {
            try (Connection connection = databaseConfiguration.getDatasource().getConnection()) {
                CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall(sql);
                callableStatement.setString(1, p1);
                callableStatement.setString(2, p2);
                callableStatement.registerOutParameter(3, Types.VARCHAR);
                callableStatement.executeUpdate();
                return  callableStatement.getString(3);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.error(e);
            }
            return null;
        });
        return role;
    }
```

If I try to execute this procedure from IntelliJ sql console, there is no problem, it works well.

How can I call this procedure from Spring Boot?

thx,
Zamek